# Special character on XML and XSLT Trans

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

My Input has the following character

```
<ws:Type="ADDRESS_LINE_1">10 S & Curley St.</ws:Address_Line_Data>
```

The `ADDRESS_LINE_1` has the special character `&` which the Oxygen XML editor is throwing error like "The entity name must immediately follow the `&` in the entity reference"

How to overcome and process the `&` value in the address field

Comment: `&` needs to be encoded to `&amp;` to make your Xml valid.

Comment: You don't overcome it. This is not well-formed XML and that is unacceptable with XML tools. Keeping XML well-formed is trivial and there is no rationale to accept anything less. There is a lot of rationale to reject it blindly though. So, change this document so that it correctly escapes its & . Don't try to beat around a toolchain so that it would accept it.

Comment: Another error is that it's closing the `<ws:Type` tag with `</ws:Address_Line_Data>`